# cmake variable "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS" can't be searched out in org

Tags: cmake

I'm a newbie to cmake and found it's very powerful but sophisticated. After reading some example and having a glance of the org, I just found that there is a very useful variable " CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS" not included in the help doc of the [org](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/search.html?q=CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS%20) website.

Could I ask how could this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Per-language variables** are described together, with `<LANG>` replacement for language name.

E.g., variable *CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS* is described as [CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html).